# Как сделать, чтоб при загрузке APK была проверка установлено ли уже это приложение?

Tags: java, android

Такой вопрос, мне необходимо реализовать такую штуку. Насколько я понимаю, при ситуации когда юзер уже имеет приложение на телефоне и тут ему высылается новый APK файл то у меня он просто не загружается(не пойму почему).

Насколько я понимаю, нужно как то реализовать такую штуку, чтоб когда юзер загружал файл поверх уже установленного приложения, старое приложение должно удаляться и новый APK устанавливается...

Я знаю, что можно попробовать реализовать такое при загрузке приложений наша аппликация проверяет имеет ли аппликация которая собирается быть установленной такой же pacage и имя и если да, то оно самоликвидируется))

Подскажите кто меня понял, как правильно поступить?

Comment: Не очень понятно... У вас не получается скачать с сети уже скачанный apk?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При установке новой версии приложения поверх уже установленного проблемы возникнут только если они подписаны разными сертификатами, в этом случае поставить новую версию можно только вручную удалив старую, программно вы на это никак повлиять не можете. Так что подписывайте релизный apk всегда одним сертификатом и у вас не будет проблем. Подробнее о процедуре подписания и генерации сертификата [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).